# Making two UIPickerView in relation to each other

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

How do I programmatically setup up the `UIPickerView` in a view without using Interface Builder? Also having trouble understanding how to do two `UIPickerView`  when I select a value from the first `UIPickerView`, second `UIPickerView`  change these values? 
first `UIPickerView`  country and seconde `UIPickerView`  city.

Comment: why don't you just combine them into one pickerview with 2 column

Comment: because i want when i select value from first UipickerView i change the content of the second.

Comment: @B.M.A You can reload the 2nd component when the user makes a choice in the first component. It's like a date picker where the days component updates when the month component changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yes possible you can create array on city within country like
int select=0;

(
   india
       (
         city,
         .....,
       )
   Australia
       (
         City,
         ......,
    )
)

and use
picker

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   if(picker==1)
   {
     return [arr_counry count];
   }
   else if(picker==2)
   {
     return [[arr_counry objectAtIndex:select] count];
   }

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  if(picker==1)
   {
     select=[arr_currency objectAtIndex:row];
    [picker reloadAllComponents];

   }
   else if(picker==2)
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link,

http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.in/2011/04/uipickerview-add-it-programmatically_04.html
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-implement-pickerview-programmatically-in-iphone/

for two picker view you can use tag values or put it in the property..